# How to Expose Mutiple Level Properties from Children in NHibernate Parent HBM

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm fairly new to NHibernate, so please bear with me.  I have a Parent Object which links to child objects in a fairly complex object model.  If I were writing SQL, my query would look like this:

```
Select A.P1, A.P2, A.BId, C.Id as BCId, D.Id As BCDId
From A
Left Join B On A.BId = B.Id
Left Join C On B.CId = C.Id
Left Join D On C.DId = D.Id
```

The resulting class would have properties to expose B.Id and C.Id instead of the objects themselves.  How can I model this in an HBM file?  I tried to use a join, but this doesn't allow for nesting, so while I can get a level or two, I can't get them all at the same time.

Comment: I think you should be using the nhibernate linq provider or the query over provider instead.  Then you can form queries like the above and even transform them into your newly created dto.

Comment: The problem is that it's a fairly large code base with all sorts of ways to get the A object.  I would have to retrofit all of those as well. The HBM would be much more convenient.

Comment: Convenient maybe but if there are that many other places using this object you would have to change those anyway to reference the newly exposed fields.  Also you would be affecting all of those other areas of code if you change the base mapping which could result in performance issues.  To answer your question though I don't think you can expose properties that are more than 1 level deep.  I've found it easier to map a single table to a single entity and create the necessary object references between each other so that you can query on these entities using the relationships between them.

Comment: I don't disagree with your suggestion in general, but, this is a special case.  I've decide to create a view and use <join/> to it for now unless someone can tell me different.  The app uses an AutoMapper to populate the dto's from entities, so it essentially loads the entire object graph.  This is everywhere as well. So, I need to reduce the footprint of the aggregate objects and reduce the chattiness. I will need to change the other code, but only where it doesn't compile.

Comment: Take a look at this article as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856329/nhibernate-mapping-a-join-on-a-joined-table

Comment: @ColeW, if you want to mark it's not possible and to use a view or split into table per entity, I will mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consensus is that this isn't possible in NHibernate and you should instead use a database view and map this to an entity, use nhibernate linq or queryover provider or use the suggestion outline in the following StackOverflow article:

[NHibernate: Mapping a join on a joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856329/nhibernate-mapping-a-join-on-a-joined-table)